# Struts 2 Request Parameter Validations (Int and Strings)

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2, url-parameters

Let's say I have this URL here

```
<s:url action ="profile" var ="profile_url">
  <s:param name = "id">${user.userId}</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href = "%{profile_url}">My Profile</s:a>
```

Where the parameter id will only have  an `int` value. So inside my Action class.

```
public class ViewProfileAction extends ActionSupport{

    public String execute(){
       //someServiceLayer.getUser(id);
       return "success";
    }

    public int getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    private int id;
}
```

Everything seems to go well as long as the user will click the link, so if the user click the link the url will be something like this

```
localhost:8090/HelloStruts2/profile?id=1
```

but what if the user manipulated the URL directly?  he manually typed in his browser a letter or a character?  like this

```
localhost:8090/HelloStruts2/profile?id=b
```

if the user did that I am sure there will be an exception or an error will occur.

My question how would I then validate the URL parameter? or if the user did such thing (entered a letter or a negative number in the parameter `id`)  I would redirect him to another page.

Comment: If you sure please tell us what an exception.

Comment: It's better to restrict the tampering url's in a custom interceptor before hitting action itself we should prevent the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a parameter field as `int` but you have set it as `String` in the URL. To eliminate the errors of that kind you need to put some interceptor before (or after it doesn't matter) the `params` interceptor to check that value. For example you put the `validation` interceptor.

```
@Action(value = "youraction", results = {
  @Result(location = "/path/to/page.jsp"),
}, interceptorRefs = {@InterceptorRef("validation"), @InterceptorRef("basicStack")})
```

then you need implement `validate()` method in your action

```
public void validate() {}
```

and finally add the method that will handle wrong and *also* good results, so OGNL will not complain

```
public void setId(String id) {
    try {
      this.id = Integer.parseInt(id);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){}
}
```

that's all, you have no exception anymore and parameter of type `String` is checked in the setter.

To your question: if you parameter didn't parsed correctly you will have value of `0` in the `execute()` method. So, you decide what result to return. You can also check the value in the `validate()` method if the `validation` interceptor placed after `params` interceptor do parse or `GenericValidator.isInt` after that `setFieldError()` and show it in the JSP or redirect right after validation.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but still, OGNL is still companing, this is the error  ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setId" failed for objectorg.hitplay.user.actions.ViewProfileAction.setId([Ljava.lang.String;)]

Comment: also why should I add the validate() method?

Comment: you needed both `validation` interceptor, `setId`, `validate()`. The last is a kind of magic. This needs for validation work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[ParametersInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ParametersInterceptor.html), using the [XWorkConverter](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/conversion/impl/XWorkConverter.html), would raise an Exception of type

> ognl.MethodFailedException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException setId(java.lang.String);

because it would search (through reflection) a `Setter` for a `String`, instead of an `int`.

This error would stop the invocation in the middle of the InterceptorStack, and would send it back with the `input` result, that is the default result for input errors in the request.

If you don't have an `input` result declared in your `struts.xml`, you will get an Exception of type

> No result defined for action your.package.your.Action and result input

If you have it, then you will be redirected back to the result declared in your `struts.xml`  (the same JSP, another JSP or an Action).

You can handle this by outputting field errors through `<s:fielderror />` tag in your JSP, and eventually coloring with red borders the fields with javascript (not in your case, because they're URL parameters).

To validate this kind of stuff properly (instead of asking Struts2 to fails and raises errors for you), you can use `XML Validation`, declaring an XML file in the same package of the Action with the name `YourActionName-validation.xml`

In your case, you should use [**Required Validator**](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/required-validator.html) and [**Int Validator**](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/int-validator.html)

(and specify `0` as `min` param in your `Int Validator`, to prevent negative values)

Comment: you are right it is returning that said error, specifically the ognl.MethodFailedException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException setId(java.lang.String); it keeps on showing on my console is there anyway to remove it? or not display it? . I just want to remove it. also I forgot about that Validation.xml didn't know it would also work for get request.

Comment: IF (and it is not mandatory) you wanna validate the errors coming from people trying to hack (or use badly) your web application, then do it. Otherwise, don't do it. But is impossible to avoid this error to show in console unless you write your own Interceptor to perform the same operations of the ValidatorInterceptor but without printing out the error... it does not make sense for me.
Just declare an input result and handle this in a pretty way in the page, showing a message like "oops i detected you tried to hack my stuff... please give me good parameters".

Comment: after reading your comment i've realized that I think it is good to show this error in the console or into to the logger for future use. I feel kinda silly now anyways thanks!