# MobileNo validation Error and datetime validation technique

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, struts-validation

I am working on Struts 2 application where am trying to provide validation for mobile number of 10 digit number .

I am allowing only 10 digit number  but even if i am entering 10 digit number it still showing validation  error message AND also want to know is there any way buy which we can perform validation for date time picker DOJO tag.

**Empaction-validation.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
"-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
"http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">

<validators>
   <field name ="firstname">
     <field-validator type="requiredstring">
      <message key="requiredstring"/>
    </field-validator>
  </field>


       <field name ="email">
        <field-validator type = "email">
        <message>provide valid Email</message>

        </field-validator>

       </field> 

   <field name ="mobileno">

    <field-validator type="long">
            <param name="min">10</param>
            <param name="max">10</param>

            <message key="stringlength" />
    </field-validator>

</field>


</validators>
```

**registation form is**

```
<%@ page language ="java" contentType ="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding ="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx" %> 
 <html>
    <head>
       <sx:head/>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src ="script.js"></script>

    </head>  

      <body>
        <div align="center"> <h1 style="color: red">  ENPLOYEE REGISTRATION FORM</h1>
       <s:form  action="emplogin"  method="post" >

      <s:textfield name="firstname" label="Employee Firstname"/>
      <s:textfield name ="lastname" label ="Last name"/>  
      <s:textfield name ="id"  label="Id"/>
      <s:radio name ="gender"   list="{'male', 'female'}" label = "Gender"/>
    <sx:datetimepicker name="dob" displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy"  label="DOB"></sx:datetimepicker> 
      <s:radio  name ="maritalstatus" list="{'singale','married'}" label="Marital Status" />

      <s:textfield name ="email" label ="Email"/>
 <sx:datetimepicker name ="joiningdate" displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" label="Joining Date"></sx:datetimepicker>

      <s:textfield name= "designation" label = "Designation"/>
      <s:textarea name ="address" label ="Address" />
      <s:textfield name = "country" label ="Country" />     
      <s:textfield name  ="state" label = "State" />
      <s:textfield name  ="city" label ="City"/> 
      <s:textfield name ="pincode" label ="Pincode"/>
      <s:textfield name ="mobileno" label="Mobile No"/>
      <s:select   name ="groups" list="{'group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3'}"  label ="Group"  cssStyle="{width:184px"/>
     <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <s:submit align="center"></s:submit>
      </s:form>
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

**in my bean class it is of `long` type**

```
package model;


public class Empmodel {
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String id;
private String gender;
private String dob;
public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
private String maritalstatus;
private String email;
private String joiningdate;
private String designation;
private String address;
private String country;
private String state;
private String city;
private int  pincode;
private long mobileno;
private String groups;
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}



public String getMaritalstatus() {
    return maritalstatus;
}
public void setMaritalstatus(String maritalstatus) {
    this.maritalstatus = maritalstatus;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getJoiningdate() {
    return joiningdate;
}
public void setJoiningdate(String joiningdate) {
    this.joiningdate = joiningdate;
}
public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}
public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}


public long getMobileno() {
    return mobileno;
}
public void setMobileno(long mobileno) {
    this.mobileno = mobileno;
}
public String getGroups() {
    return groups;
}
public void setGroups(String groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}
public int getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}
public void setPincode(int pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

}
```

Comment: This is because the field type is long, change it to string type and check how it works.

Comment: Roman C  After changing it to string type its working but in  wrong way . I accepting less than 10  digit or more than 10 digit so there is no effect of validation logic

Comment: You are probably need some expression that checks the length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That using the `stringlenth` validator you can validate the length of the string. Check the [stringlength validator](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/stringlength-validator.html).

And using the `date` validator you can validate the date format. Check the [date validator](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/date-validator.html).

If you want to validate datetime picker  using `validate()` you should use the logic that is to parse the value returned by the picker using `SimpleDateFormat` if you are not using other date time libraries like [JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and don't care about timezone then you should create `ThreadLocal` parser for datetimes.

**EDIT:**

**validators.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator Config 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-config-1.0.dtd">

<validators>
  <validator name="longlength" class="jspbean.struts.vaidators.LongLengthFieldValidator"/>
</validators>
```

**LongLengthFieldValidator.java**

```
public class LongLengthFieldValidator extends FieldValidatorSupport {

  private boolean doTrim = true;
  private int maxLength = -1;
  private int minLength = -1;


  public void setMaxLength(int maxLength) {
    this.maxLength = maxLength;
  }

  public int getMaxLength() {
    return maxLength;
  }

  public void setMinLength(int minLength) {
    this.minLength = minLength;
  }

  public int getMinLength() {
    return minLength;
  }

  public void setTrim(boolean trim) {
    doTrim = trim;
  }

  public boolean getTrim() {
    return doTrim;
  }

  public void validate(Object object) throws ValidationException {
    String fieldName = getFieldName();
    String val = getFieldValue(fieldName, object).toString();

    if (val == null || val.length() <= 0) {
      // use a required validator for these
      return;
    }
    if (doTrim) {
      val = val.trim();
      if (val.length() <= 0) {
        // use a required validator
        return;
      }
    }

    if ((minLength > -1) && (val.length() < minLength)) {
      addFieldError(fieldName, object);
    } else if ((maxLength > -1) && (val.length() > maxLength)) {
      addFieldError(fieldName, object);
    }
  }
}
```

**XXX-validation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>

  <validator type="longlength">
                <param name="fieldName">mobileno</param>
                <param name="minLength">10</param>
               <param name="maxLength">10</param>
               <param name="trim">true</param>
               <message>Your mobileno number needs to be 10 characters long</message>
  </validator>
</validators>
```

Comment: In  Model class i am using long type for mobile number . so if i use string type of validation for mobile no . Will it be any mismatch & where i can use long type......

Comment: You could have both long and string setters due to the overloading. OGNL will use the string one however.

Comment: Now its giving me this king of error 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String'

Comment: You need some kind of conversion that cast the string to the long type. See [Struts2 Request Parameter Validations(Int and Strings)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396601/struts2-request-parameter-validationsint-and-strings/14403722#14403722)

Comment: I am not getting can you explain  how to use  Struts2 Request Parameter Validations(Int and Strings

Comment: In Empmodel clas mobile no is of long type

Comment: The field type should be `String` if you want to use `StringLengthFieldValidator` or write your own custom validator for type long.