# Struts 2 validation.xml not working

Tags: xml, validation, struts2

I am trying to do simple validation using validaton.xml, the validation is working for username which is of type string but not for password which is of type int.

Action class

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport  {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5271055255991498361L;
private String username;
private int password;

public String execute() {

    if (this.username.equals("admin")&& this.password==123) {
        addActionMessage("Welcome admin");
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        addActionError("Invalid credentials");
        return ERROR;
    }
}

public String getUsername() {

    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {

    this.username = username;
}

public int getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(int password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

LoginAction-validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators> 
    <field name="username"> 
        <field-validator type="requiredstring"> 
            <message>Please enter a user name</message> 
        </field-validator> 
    </field> 

    <field name="password"> 
        <field-validator type="required"> 
            <message>Please enter a password</message> 
        </field-validator> 
    </field> 
</validators>
```

struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />

    <package name="user" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="net.training.user.action.LoginAction"   method="execute">
          <result name = "input">Login.jsp</result>
          <result name = "error">Login.jsp</result>    
          <result name= "success">/customer/CustomerForm.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

The error reported was

```
WARNING: Error setting expression 'password' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1f2428d'
ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setPassword" failed for object net.training.user.action.LoginAction@1d532ae [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.training.user.action.LoginAction.setPassword([Ljava.lang.String;)]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1305)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.training.user.action.LoginAction.setPassword([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1246)
    ... 63 more
/-- Encapsulated exception ------------\
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.training.user.action.LoginAction.setPassword([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1246)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
    ...
\--------------------------------------/
Jul 24, 2013 3:26:18 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor error
SEVERE: Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'password' on 'class net.training.user.action.LoginAction: Error setting expression 'password' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1f2428d'
Error setting expression 'password' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1f2428d' - Class: ognl.OgnlRuntime
File: OgnlRuntime.java
Method: callAppropriateMethod
Line: 1305 - ognl/OgnlRuntime.java:1305:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.handleOgnlException(OgnlValueStack.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:172)
    ...
Caused by: ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setPassword" failed for object net.training.user.action.LoginAction@1d532ae [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.training.user.action.LoginAction.setPassword([Ljava.lang.String;)]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1305)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.training.user.action.LoginAction.setPassword([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1246)
    ... 63 more
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>

<s:actionerror/>
<s:fielderror/>

<s:form action="login" method="post" namespace="/" > 
    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
    <s:textfield name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />
    <s:submit  />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Struts version : 2.3.15

Comment: That's clearly not a validation issue, rather a config or form issue. Setting ints works, so I suspect something else is wrong, but cannot test anything at this time.

Comment: @DaveNewton give me some direction, where should I look into.. I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: What version of S2? What's the form look like? Do you have a SSCCE on github/etc I can check out?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have edited to add the details

Comment: Also, I'm not excited about using an int field for a password; you lose a lot of flexibility this way.

Comment: @DaveNewton no I am just learning struts..I wanted to test the requiredfieldvalidator using annotation first, it did not work..so I wanted to check whether it works in XML.

Comment: You should not enter not integer values into the password field.

Comment: @RomanC If I enter non integer values, it shows error but it throws the same exception as above. But if I submit empty it does not validate. why?

Comment: @user1448660 Because it's searching for the method `setPassword(int` and couldn't find it, then fallback to `setPassword(String[]`, which fails.

Comment: @RomanC If I put requiredstring then it prevents form submission but it throws the same exception as above.

Comment: @RomanC how to put a required condition for int field without any exception.

Comment: @user1448660 This warning appears only when you use devMode. Turn it off and it should disappear.

Comment: @user1448660 Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396601/struts2-request-parameter-validationsint-and-strings/14403722#14403722).

Answer (score 0):

IMO looks like that you're using a `required` for an `int` field. I guess you should use an `int` type of validator. The required validator checks for `null`, [struts2 required validator](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/required-validator.html).

You should do something like:

```
   <field name="password"> 
        <field-validator type="int"> 
            <param name="min">0</param>
            <message>Please enter a password</message> 
        </field-validator> 
    </field> 
</validators>
```

Comment: if I put some range which doesn't include zero then it does the validation...but if the range contains zero it submits the empty form...but in both the cases it throws the exception that I mentioned in my ques.. it should be possible to put required condition for int field without mentioning any range.

Answer (score 0):

If I use Integer instead of int then it works fine.